# Using Knockout JS to communicate with rest service?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Hi im going for a final job interview , I have no prior working knowledge of knockout js and they want me to in 2.5 hours to build an MVC4 website using knockout.js which will call into an ASP.NET WebAPI REST service to retrieve data.

build a website that does display updates without posting back, using knockout JS.

some styling is required .

if time permits you will be able to add extra features to the REST service.

For those with knowledge of knockout JS how difficult is this to learn, I have partial JS knowledge and experience of c# , mvc3 and html.Where can I find information on how to do this?.

Thanks

Comment: I have to ask: how did the interview go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KO has one of the better tutorial sites around. I would suggest you spend some time there.

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Also, KO will not directly communicate with a REST service. KO builds upon and binds to model data (JavaScript objects) which can be populated from REST services via AJAX requests but there is no direct connection between the service and your model data. KO provides the glue or plumbing between the UI and model.

I am no expert with KO. I played with it as part of an experimental project last year. It is complicated enough that I have forgotten just about all that I learnt having not used it for some time. I think you will have a difficult time cramming for an interview. Better to just be honest about your level of knowledge. Maybe bring in some work you were able to complete based on the tutorials.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your advice